# Finding relation between inputs and outputs

Tags: numerical-methods, data-analysis

Is anyone able to find the rule? If possible, can you explain how and what's the name of that kind of rule?

- Input  Output
- 0,18       0,316
- 0,3       0,432
- 0,32       0,4536
- 0,33       0,4644
- 0,34       0,4752
- 0,353  0,4892
- 0,354  0,4903
- 0,36     0,4968
- 0,365  0,5022

Thanks a lot to anyone willing to help me!

Comment: Have you plotted them to see what it looks like?  That is always the first step.  Does it look like a straight line?  What is the significance of multiple entries with the same input and output?

Comment: It've very nearly linear.  $y=1.0065x+.133$ is a solid fit, $r^2=.999$

Comment: There is no meaning to the multiple value, I should remove them. I will try to plot them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Standard fitting programs yield:

$y = 0.17595 + 0.661938 x + 0.643346 x^2$

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the four points at $0.10 \lt x \lt 0.15$?  I don't see them in the data.  I see a lot more points with $x \gt 0.3$ than your plot, as well.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a lot!